# Can't return QStringList from lambda into a function

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I'm trying to fill the combobox in QT 5.7 using following code:

```
ui->comboBox_2->addItems([]() -> QStringList {
        QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
        int current_year = date.toString("yyyy").toInt();
        QStringList year_list;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            year_list << QString::number(current_year - (50 - i));
        }
        return year_list;
    });
```

But it gives me this error: `no viable conversion from '(lambda at ..)' to 'const QStringList'`
What's the problem?

Comment: The problem really is given in the error message: you're passing the instance of the lambda to `addItems`, and it doesn't know what to do with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addItems expects a QStringList, not a lambda that produces a QStringList, so you have to call your lambda to get the QStringList:

```
ui->comboBox_2->addItems([]() { ... }());
```

Comment: It works, but I'm confused... I thought you didn't need to call lambda in order for it to return value. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @7Y3RPXK3ETDCNRDD A lambda is a value - an instance of a functor - it's a compiler-generated class. In your case it'd be an instance of a class that has `QStringList operator()()` member. The `addItems` function doesn't want an instance of that class, it wants an instance of `QStringList`! There's no user-defined conversion, the class doesn't have a `operator QStringList()`.

Answer (score 1):

include () at the end of {} to explicitly call this lambda function.